# Capybara method is unacceptable from the calss undefined method `expect' for #<ArticleForm:0xb5e98bc>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

The method "expect" it not accessible when trying to call from a class method. However, it works fine when calling from the feature spec.So basically the last method (i_expect_to_see_article_on_home_page) is not working.

## spec/support/ArticleForm.rb

```
    require 'rails_helper'

class ArticleForm
  include Capybara::DSL


  def visit_home_page
    visit('/')
    self
  end

  def create_an_article
    click_on('New Article')
    fill_in('Title', with: "My title")
    fill_in('Content', with: "My content")
    click_on('Create Article')
    self
  end

  def i_expect_to_see_article_on_home_page
    visit('/')
    expect(page).to have_text("My title")
    expect(page).to have_text("My content")
    self
  end
end
```

## spec/features/article_spec.rb

```
 require 'rails_helper'

require_relative '../support/ArticelForm.rb'
feature "home page" do
  article_form = ArticleForm.new

  scenario  "Visit the home page and post an article" do
    article_form.visit_home_page.create_an_article
    article_form.visit_home_page.i_expect_to_see_article_on_home_page
  end
end
```

Comment: You have too many `end`'s in the article spec.  Can you correct it please

Comment: what's the error you are getting?

Comment: undefined method `have_content'  or 
undefined method `expect' for #<ArticleForm:0xc2df79c>
       Did you mean?  exec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `include RSpec::Matchers` in your object.  You will probably also need to do the same with Capybara::RSpecMatchers if you want to use the capybara matchers

Comment: it's RSpec::Matchers you need to include to get `expect`

Answer (score 0):

Im not familiar with the syntax you're using but I believe you need to wrap it into "it block".This is how I normally write it:

```
describe "i_expect_to_see_article_on_home_page" do
  it 'should do something' do
    visit('/')
    expect(page).to have_text("My title")
    expect(page).to have_text("My content")
  end
end
```

Comment: `scenario` works the same as `it` on feature specs.  Not sure if it's just an alias but I'd assume so

Comment: I'm trying to simplify the spec by creating a class with 2 methods. One method to create a post and another one to check if it was created. I'm doing this so I can centralise my code and use it in different places. It looks like Capybara is just not available inside the second method of the ArticleForm class.

Comment: @Faisal expect is an rspec thing, not Capybara which would explain your issue

Comment: @fabersky still an issue unfortunately.

Comment: @j-dexx I see. what should I replace it with?

Comment: I have replaced expect(page).to have_text

Comment: @j-dexx Correct - scenario is just an alias for the example (it), and feature is an alias for example group (describe) that additionally sets `type: :feature` metadata on the group